# How can I add an image from a relative URL to be displayed in a ContentQuery WebPart?

Tags: content-query-web-part, relative-path

I created a Content Query webpart that dynamically feeds from different blog posts from different  sites and subsites. Now: I am trying to set up the Query so that a logo would appear as the Rollup image depending on the site/subsite it's issued from.

Is there a way for me to put in a relative URL so that every time a team posts something, my query would show the TeamIcon.gif that I stored for them under their site assets?

Also, would the relative URL be: ~site/SiteAsstes/TeamIcon.gif ?
*Also, I am not a programmer*